# How to create custom 403 page for a particular content type?

Tags: 6, nodes

For a particular content type in my Drupal 6 web site, I do not want the users to see the "access denied" message when viewing an unpublished node. Instead I want to show a more meaningful message.
I have tried various modules like http://drupal.org/project/customerror, but I can't find a way to restrict the message for only a single content type.
There is a similar question here http://drupal.org/node/888312.

Do you have any suggestion on how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the [Custom 403](http://drupal.org/project/custom_403) module, or the [Teaser 403](http://drupal.org/project/teaser_403) module .

> #### Custom 403
>
> This module provides helpful messages to users when they encounter a 403 (Access Denied) page. Depending on different role(s) permissions set on the specific node or content type, the administrator can specify messages accordingly. The user who encounters the 403 will obtain more specific information on how to obtain the role(s) required to access the node.

> #### Teaser 403
>
> This module is designed to expose teaser content for sites which normally require users to login to view nodes.