# Customize "Access Denied" (403) page for specific content type

Tags: 8, users, redirection

I'm currently setting up a simple LMS in Drupal 8 and would like to customize the *Access Denied* page as follows:

- **Anonymous users** should be redirected to the *Login* page, when they hit a 403 error.
- **Logged in users** trying to access a **specific content type** (a Course),
  which they are not allowed to access, should be redirected to a
  custom message (telling them to buy the course or something like
  that). It would be even better, if they could be shown the teaser of
  that node, but that's not a necessity.
- In all other cases, I would like to show a general *Access Denied* page.

Fwiw, there were similiar questions for D6 [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10863/how-to-create-custom-403-page-for-a-particular-content-type) and [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/888312) that also didn't receive any good replies.

Does anybody happen to know a good solution (for D8)?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use an exception subscriber, D8 provides a base class HttpExceptionSubscriberBase where you can put the code in `on403()`,  see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165884/how-to-redirect-an-anonymous-user-to-the-login-form-after-a-403-error/245211#245211.

Comment: What!? I've been on this platform for quite a while (in different sections) and I do know the rules, but I'm completely at a loss, as to why my question is supposed to be "primarily opinion-based"? I'm looking for help solving a specific problem, not for ideas as to which module is the coolest... (And why hasn't the question that I mentioned been put on hold? It's virtually the same question, except it's for D6.)

Comment: @4k4: Thanks for your suggestion. This sounds like a more complex route and, frankly, I was hoping for a slightly simpler solution. But I will try your idea as soon as possible and will report back. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that using the rules module.

Create a rule using the Rules module, with as Event something like `After visiting node no_access`. So that the entire rule configuration would look something like this:

**Events:** After visiting node no_access

**Conditions:**
        User has role - Parameter: User: [site:current-user], Roles: anonymous user
        NOT Text comparison - Parameter: Text: [site:current-page:url], Matching text: user/login

**Actions:** Page redirect - Parameter: URL: user/login

And then for the logged in user, you can create another rule that checks if the user is logged in, and then redirects to a custom page if the user visits a `no_access` page.

For the general access denied page, you can set a url in `Admin > Configuration > System > Site information`, under error pages.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That sounds great and simple, will try that. I didn't know that the Rules module is already usable for D8...

Comment: Cool, glad that you could use the help :)

Comment: Please write if you get it to work

Comment: I just tried to create the rule, but unfortunately I'm already failing at the first stage: There doesn't seem to be an event like "after visiting node no access". Am I missing something? Maybe this event is still missing in the D8 version?

Comment: Well, this issue is for drupal 7, but maybe something might be useful, https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/issues/796056